# How to get multiple columns value from all the tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the column values from all the tables, I have some tables which contain group_name and date and so far, I need only the group_name and date values from all the tables

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

Here is my query (query is returning nothing)

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'group_name' AND column_name = 'date'
```

so the output should be something like this

[image]

Note: I don't want to specify the table names because there will be many tables. I have shown only two and table names are dynamic and can be deleted or created from the frontend

Comment: Just think about it: how can a value in column be 'group_name' _and_ 'date' at the same time? It has to be 'group_name' or 'date'.

Comment: yea, I know my query is wrong just because of this line `AND column_name = 'date'` so I am finding what is the query to get my output result

Comment: Just use OR not AND, or use `column_name IN ('group_name', 'date')`

Comment: This question is exactly the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425767/how-to-get-multiple-columns-value-from-all-tables-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Store the names of the frontend created tables in another table named say user_tables. Use:

```
SELECT table_name from user_tables
```

This returns a list of tables names `["table1", "table2", "table3"]`. Then dynamically generate the sql from the list of table names:

```
SELECT group_name, date FROM table1
UNION
SELECT group_name, date FROM table2
UNION
SELECT group_name, date FROM table3
```

Comment: yes something like this but without specifying the table name, because I will have more tables in future which can be created from the frontend

Comment: @Jerin using another table to store the table names makes this problem much cleaner to solve without worrying about other tables in the future that might happen to have the columns group_name and date.